# android posting json with HttpClient crash

Tags: android, json, http, gson

I have a project where im using HttpClient but it crashes,

my json is logging fine,

I have internet permission,

I tested my request in HTTPClient, and is working,

but I dont know why is crashing?

here my code,

```
public void empaquetaYmanda() {

        Log.d("mensa", "empaquetaYmanda copio");


        //build my dictionary!
        Map<String, String> comment = new HashMap<String, String>();
        comment.put("resource_uri", "pa que esto");
        comment.put("guid", "345");
        comment.put("dob", "13-07-1990");
        comment.put("address", "23 rue sante");
        comment.put("name", "Sakuraba");
        comment.put("mobile", "333456888");
        comment.put("email", "saku@sa.sss");
        comment.put("points", "333999");
        comment.put("surname", "Cerezin");
        comment.put("devicetoken", "token334455Droid");

        Log.d("mensa", "tu dicto :: " + comment);

        //lo serializo dicto a json
        String json = new GsonBuilder().create().toJson(comment, Map.class);

        Log.d("mensa", "tu json :: " + json);

        postData("http://sasa.com/api/v1/client/", json); //my

    }


    public void postData(String uri, String json) {
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(uri);


     // Url Encoding the POST parameters
            try {
                Log.d("mensa", "tu Encoding");

                httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity(json)); //revisa!
                //httppost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // writing error to Log
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Log.d("mensa", "tu request::"+httppost);


            // Making HTTP Request
            try {
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                // writing response to log
                Log.d("Http Response:", response.toString());
                Log.d("mensa", "tu respuesta ::"+response.toString());

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // writing exception to log
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // writing exception to log
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

    }
```

here the error log

```
02-22 06:17:40.980: E/AndroidRuntime(19016): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-22 06:17:40.980: E/AndroidRuntime(19016): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.hyper.gsonex/com.hyper.gsonex.Main}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
02-22 06:17:40.980: E/AndroidRuntime(19016):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
02-22 06:17:40.980: E/AndroidRuntime(19016):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
02-22 06:17:40.980: E/AndroidRuntime(19016):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
02-22 06:17:40.980: E/AndroidRuntime(19016):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
02-22 06:17:40.980: E/AndroidRuntime(19016):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-22 06:17:40.980: E/AndroidRuntime(19016):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-22 06:17:40.980: E/AndroidRuntime(19016):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
02-22 06:17:40.980: E/AndroidRuntime(19016):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-22 06:17:40.980: E/AndroidRuntime(19016):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-22 06:17:40.980: E/AndroidRuntime(19016):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-22 06:17:40.980: E/AndroidRuntime(19016):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-22 06:17:40.980: E/AndroidRuntime(19016):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-22 06:17:40.980: E/AndroidRuntime(19016): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
02-22 06:17:40.980: E/AndroidRuntime(19016):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
02-22 06:17:40.980: E/AndroidRuntime(19016):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
02-22 06:17:40.980: E/AndroidRuntime(19016):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
02-22 06:17:40.980: E/AndroidRuntime(19016):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
02-22 06:17:40.980: E/AndroidRuntime(19016):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
02-22 06:17:40.980: E/AndroidRuntime(19016):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
02-22 06:17:40.980: E/AndroidRuntime(19016):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
02-22 06:17:40.980: E/AndroidRuntime(19016):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
02-22 06:17:40.980: E/AndroidRuntime(19016):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
02-22 06:17:40.980: E/AndroidRuntime(19016):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
02-22 06:17:40.980: E/AndroidRuntime(19016):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
02-22 06:17:40.980: E/AndroidRuntime(19016):    at com.hyper.gsonex.Main.postData(Main.java:116)
02-22 06:17:40.980: E/AndroidRuntime(19016):    at com.hyper.gsonex.Main.empaquetaYmanda(Main.java:85)
02-22 06:17:40.980: E/AndroidRuntime(19016):    at com.hyper.gsonex.Main.onCreate(Main.java:46)
02-22 06:17:40.980: E/AndroidRuntime(19016):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
02-22 06:17:40.980: E/AndroidRuntime(19016):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
02-22 06:17:40.980: E/AndroidRuntime(19016):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to perform network operation on the UI thread that's why it throws NetWorkOnUIThreadException. Try to kept your network related code in separate thread and execute it.
Better solution would be using the Async Task.

Answer (score 1):

You can't make HTTP requests on your main thread, you have to do them in an AsyncTask or Thread

Comment: Remarkably ... exactly what that error message says.

Comment: Yeah, I need a karma bot that posts this in any thread that has NetworkOnMainThread error.